# How to run Karma with Firefox using Xvfb?

Tags: firefox, karma-runner

I want to start Firefox using [Xvfb](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.6/doc/man/man1/Xvfb.1.xhtml) to run [Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/index.html) in a headless server.

Karma needs a launcher plugin to start and stop browsers automatically. I've found a [karma-xvfb-chrome-launcher](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-xvfb-chrome-launcher), but no one for Firefox.

After installing Xvfb (Ubuntu), I know I can start Firefox using the following command:

```
$ xvfb-run firefox <app-under-test-url>
```

What I don't know is how to make Karma start Firefox this way.

Is there a way to provide a custom start/stop browser script to Karma work with?

Is possible to do it via *Karma.conf.js*?

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `xvfb-run` to start Karma, and any browser it launches will run in a new Xvfb instance.

In a `Makefile` of mine I have this command which is run when I want to run my Karma-based tests:

```
xvfb-run karma start --single-run
```

`xvfb-run` operates by starting an Xvfb instance, grabbing its display number and setting the `DISPLAY` environment variable, then it runs the command you passed as argument. This means that everything that is executing through `xvfb-run` (including any new processes started from the initial one) is using the `DISPLAY` value that `xvfb-run` has set and consequently will appear on the Xvfb instance that `xvfb-run` started.

Answer (score 0):

Considering [Louis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1906307/louis)'s answer...

As I'm using Angular 2 with typscript, I've made it work adding the following lines to my *package.json* file:

> "test": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
>   "test-once": "tsc && karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
>   "test-xvfb": "xvfb-run npm run test-once",

Now, when I run tests this way:

`$ npm run test-xvfb`

No browser window is open at all!